# NCVIEWER : print moves and non-print moves should be different color

Tags: colors

I see toolpath/print moves and non-print moves ALL the same (blue) color that makes it almost unreadable.
I would like to see non-print (and retracted) moves displayed a different (light) color - If it is possible.

I guess ncviewer makes the difference by speed values: when speed is a limit higher than drawing speed then it changes color. But I use relatively low non-print moving speeds (as my printer is old and shaky) so I think ncviewer can not make the difference.
How can I adjust this speed limit i.e. color change?
Note: Backplotter Setting / Show Rapid Movement is in OFF position. No change if I select it ON.